# Laravel 5 authentication issue with Active Directory

Tags: laravel, authentication, active-directory, ldap, multiple-domains

I'm using laravel 5.1 for authenticating users from active directory. The package I'm using is http://packalyst.com/packages/package/strebl/l5-ldap-auth and everything worked fine when I was authenticating users only from one domain.

Now I have a request to authenticate users from **multiple domains** and I have made the following change:
1. In the users table I have created column "domain"
2. I have created a second adldap.php file (adldap2.php) in config directory
3.In LdapAuthManager.php file (getLdapConfig method), I choose which config file to call depending on which user is trying to login.

**Issue:**
When user is trying to authenticate for the first time (Auth::attempt($credentials)) is returning false, but **if he tries again he can be successfully authenticated.**
Also if user "user01" from domain @corp.int is logged in and after that, user "user2" from domain @domain2.int is logged in, when the session of "user01" ends and he tries to login again, the first time he cannot be authenticated but the **second time he can**.

Please advice.